# How to instantiate a class multiple times that implements runnable and opens socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, runnable

I'm working on a project in which I have a class, `DeviceCommunicator`, that `implements Runnable`. Currently, a main class instantiates a single instance of `DeviceCommunicator` which (eventually) connects to a device on the local network using the `Socket` library.

By eventually, I mean that if a message needs to be sent, then the instance of the `DeviceCommunicator` opens the socket connection to the device, sends the message, and then **starts a new thread to receive the data back from the socket** via the following line of code:

```
new Thread(new DeviceCommunicator()).start();
```

EDIT: To clarify, this is the order of operations when the program is executed:

1) `MAIN` class instantiates a `DeviceCommunicator` class w/ constructor like:

`comm1 = DeviceCommunicator(hostName, portNum)`

2) `MAIN` class wants to send a message to `comm1`, so it calls `send` like:

`comm1.send(someString)`

3) comm1 is of type `DeviceCommunicator` and opens a `Socket` connection to hostName/portNum like:

```
deviceSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNum);
out = new PrintStream(deviceSocket.getOutputStream());
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(deviceSocket.getInputStream()));
```

4) comm1 sends `someStr` to the output `PrintStream` and then initializes a thread to listen for a response with the following code:

```
new Thread(new DeviceCommunicator()).start();
```

Due to the fact that the listening `DeviceCommunicator` thread has no constructor arguments, it was required that I make the output `PrintStream` and the input `BufferedReader` `static` variables.

When I have only one instance of `DeviceCommunicator` - this works great!

However, I would like multiple instances of the `DeviceCommunicator` class that can connect to either the same or a different device on the local network, **BUT** considering the fact that the output and input in the `DeviceCommunicator` class are `static`, then they are shared (I think, I've read that the JVM doesn't quite guarantee that static variable changes will be made visible to other running threads) across all instances of `DeviceCommunicator` - this is a problem!

I've done some research and I haven't come across quite a similar topic - most topics are basically an "either-or" where:

A) The topic is about threaded socket communication, wherein "non-blocking" communication is accomplished by the use of static variables.

or

B) A simple `implements Runnable` case is considered wherein one thread will accomplish one (typically simple) task while the other accomplishes another (typically slightly modified) task.

EDIT: I guess one solution that might be proposed is to simply pass the input `BufferedReader` to the listening `DeviceCommunicator` thread, however I am implementing a queue of messages that are to be sent (in case there are network problems); so, if a message needs to be sent, it simply gets the first element in the queue and prints it to the socket connection, and I would like to, in the listening thread, verify that the message was correctly received by the device. If the message was correctly received, then I would like to remove the element from the queue, **but** this again poses a problem - passing variables in Java is always by value, not by reference! So, if I was to pass the input `BufferedReader` **and** the queue, the queue that was being modified in the listening `DeviceCommunicator` would not be the actual queue that needed to be modified in the main `DeviceCommunicator` instance.

Is there an obvious solution to this problem that I am unaware of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `DeviceCommunicator` your class?  Why do you have to use `static` variables for the streams?  My can't you add a new contructor?

Comment: Yes, `DeviceCommunicator` is the class that is instantiated by some `Main` class. I guess my thought for using `static` variables for the streams (and I thought this was explained already, so please educate me as I seem to be not in the know), was so that the listening `DeviceCommunicator` thread was reading from the same input `BufferedReader` that the main `DeviceCommunicator` established when creating the `Socket` connection. I'll add some more code to see if I can clear anything up.

Comment: Java always "pass by value" but that is misleading.  If the argument is an object (like a queue) then both the caller and the callee will have a reference to the same object.  Any queue operations will be seen by both threads.

Comment: I just edited the post to (hopefully) provide a little more clarification.

Comment: So, if my input was of type `BufferedReader` and queue was of type `ArrayList<String>`, then I could simply pass both of those two values to the listening thread (like in step 4 above, but with passed vars)? That is, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for your very quick reply to my question =)

Comment: Aha, I think for the now I have it working - I had my blinders on about creating a listening thread that had no constructor arguments (went through too many bare minimum tutorials). I haven't verified yet that the ArrayLists are working properly, but if you'd submit an answer to the question in the form of "passing `BufferedReader` to the listening thread and the fact that objects, although passed by value, are valid as the object itself is the reference" then I'd be happy to call it an answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the `DeviceCommunicator` class, I would pass in the `Stream` or `Reader` objects that you need as arguments to the constructor.  I certainly would *not* use `static` variables in that manner.

```
new Thread(new DeviceCommunicator(hostName, portNum, in, out)).start();
```

Now, if multiple threads are reading and writing out the streams then you will have to synchronize on them before doing that.

You also mentioned in your comments that you need to have a `Queue` of messages to send.  That also could be an argument to the `DeviceCommunicator` although you will need to make that a synchronized list or something:

```
List<String> toSendList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
...
new Thread(new DeviceCommunicator(hostName, portNum, in, out, toSendList)).start();
```

However, a better pattern would be to add a `send` method on the `DeviceCommunicator` that would add the items to the queue instead of both the main thread and the sending thread having the same queue.  If you add methods to `DeviceCommunicator`, you might be able to have it also hide the reader and writer streams as well and the main thread would not access the streams directly.  [Data hiding](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_05.htm) is one of the important features of object oriented programs.

Comment: +1 for hiding the queue inside the DC class. Some consideration should be given for an error strategy.  That's one reason I always go for a 'TheadComms' class for communicating to and from threads - as well as buffered data, it can hold error messages, exception objects etc. as well. If you are going to fire something through events like 'OnDataRx' or 'OnError', it should not be a stream instance :)

Comment: Good points @Martin but why wouldn't you just add that functionality to the `DC` class?  Or do you have a class that you use for all of your thread returns.  So you'd create `new ThreadComm<ReturnClass>()` and pass it into the `DC` constructor with `Future`-ish functionality?  That _would_ be a nice pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for the past few days but thank you for the detailed answer! I do have a question however - you mention adding a `send` method to the `DC` class that would "add the items to the queue." It sounds like in this case, do the main and listener classes both not have the same queue? The way I've got things running so far seems to probably not quite be the optimal solution - my main `DC` class is the one that actually sends the message through the socket and then instantiates a listener `DC` class to process the response, and what I think I'm hearing is why not let the listener

Comment: My point @MandM is that the main class should not have direct access to the queue at all.  The queue should be hidden inside of the `DC` class.  So the `send()` method on `DC` would add it to the internal queue that is `private` to `DC`.

Comment: just handle both sending and receiving, while the main `DC` class basically just spawns independent `DC` send/receive threads that only have knowledge about their one message. Is this sounding right or am I way out of left field? (Sorry I had to break up my response, but there's just so much to say!) Thanks again, guys!

Comment: No, I'd have a `DC` thread handle a connection -- not a single message.  Then the main thread would add many messages to the same `DC`.  See my previous comment about your `send()` question.

Comment: I have an actual `Main` class that is much more high level than the actual `DC` classes. _That_ `Main` class has no access to the queue/in/out/etc that is in the `DC` at all. However, when I instantiate a `DC` class, it simply has the hostname/port information given from "above." When a message actually needs to be sent, my `DC` class instantiates another `DC` thread that I'm thinking should handle sending/receiving, so multiple messages can be processed at simultaneously. I'm sorry if I'm explaining something you already understand, I'm just trying to make sure we're all level-set.

Comment: That is why I'm using the terms "main `DC`" and listener `DC`.

Comment: You cannot be using the reader and writers to the socket at the same time from multiple threads, right @MandM?  I don't like the idea of a "main `DC`".  I'd create a another class for that.  Maybe `DCManager` or some such.  Without seeing your code I can't be more help to understand what tasks should be in `main`, `main DC`, and the `DC`.  Just that you should have 1 thread per connection, and hide the queue inside of the `DC`.

Comment: There is currently a `send()` method in `DC` that does exactly what you are mentioning - it adds the message that is to be sent to that device to a queue which is then handled with a fixed rate timer. The following is the setup as of now: if there is no message being processed, the `DC` class sends a message through the socket, and then instantiates a listening `DC` thread to process the response. First - does this seem like a viable setup? It makes sense to me, but then again I'm fairly new to Java (not that this is quite a Java question, but more of an architecture question).

Comment: To your last response, the main `DC` class _only_ uses the output writer, and the listening `DC` class _only_ uses the input reader. I do agree that it sounds better to have a `DCManager` class, and I'll look into getting that set up. This should be pretty simple, as I am the master (aka, only person) working on this project, so the code is mine to do what I want with, lucky me :) Thank you for the help and suggestions Gray!

Comment: That sounds ok.  Maybe `DC` and `DCReader` or something would be better names.  Whatever.  As long as you don't have 2 readers then I think you are fine.  Good luck!

Comment: OK, so I've got one more question/situation to handle. If I've sent a message, I don't want to send subsequent messages until the first has been processed completely. Using the terms `DC` and `DCReader`, my `DC` first checks a `processing` flag - if false, a message gets sent through the socket, the `processing` flag gets set to true, and then the `DCReader` handles the message response. I would like for the `DCReader` to somehow send some indication to back to `DC` to set `processing` back to false once the `DCReader` has completed. Is there a simple way to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: I've seen some things about `Callable` but I don't think returning a value from a task is really what I'm after... again, thanks in advance!

Comment: So this sounds to me that you should not have a separate reader class then.  I would just have a `DC` class.  `send()` externally just adds to your send queue.  Internally the thread sends the request and then waits for the response.  This is a _not_ simpler.  It removes a thread.  Then the `main` thread just adds to the internal `DC` queue.

Comment: I was a little confused by your post a few days ago Gray, but I think the __not__ was supposed to be __lot__, as I was thinking condensing sender/receiver into a single thread would be easier (and it has been). Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sorry @MandM, you are correct that the "not simpler" should be "lot simpler".  Does my answer deserve a check mark at this point?

Comment: Hey Gray, sorry for the radio silence, I've been away for a little while, but indeed it does - thanks again for the help.